# JW Player - how to send user to a certain url when they click on the video

Tags: flash, video, flv, jwplayer

When the user clicks on the video once its ended id like it to pop up a window with a new url in it - how can i do this in jw player?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the pop up in the player you'll need to create a flash plugin for it.

If you want a javascript alert, you can do something like this.

```
jwplayer().onComplete(videoEnded)

function videoEnded()
{
    alert("Your Message: and url"); 
}
```

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12540/javascript-api-reference

Or for the Flash plugin
http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/17679/building-flash-plugins